# Trouble joining a list of multiple strings back to a list of a single string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a Python program to check if the phrases in a file occur in a document. My program works fine until it hits a phrase such as "happy(+) feet". I think the error is related to the "(+)" in the phrase; however, I am not sure how to revise my regular expression to make it work.

This is my code:

```
import re
handle = open('document.txt', 'r')
text = handle.read()

lst = list()
with open('phrases.txt', 'r') as phrases:
    for phrase in phrases:
        phrase = phrase.rstrip()
        if len(phrase) > 0 and phrase not in lst:
            ealst.append(phrase)

counts = {}
for each_phrase in lst:
    word = each_phrase.rsplit()
    pattern = re.compile(r'%s' % '\s+'.join(word), re.IGNORECASE)
    counts[each_phrase] = len(pattern.findall(text))

for key, value in counts.items():
    if value > 0:
       print key,',', value

 handle.close()
 phrases.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) when declaring a `word`:

```
word = map(re.escape, each_phrase.rsplit())
```

And perhaps, change `\s+` to `\s*` to make the space optional:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'%s' % '\s*'.join(word), re.IGNORECASE)
```

The round brackets `(` and `)` as well as `+` plus symbol being [special regex characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) must be escaped in a regular expression outside of character class to match literal characters.

Sample [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DRsqVq)